# Python & Amazon EC2 -- Recommended Library?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

What is the recommended library for `python` to do everything that is `Amazon EC2` related?

I came across `boto` and `libcloud`. Which one is easier to use? does `libcloud` offer the same functionality as `boto`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The big advantage of `libcloud` is that it provides a unified interface to multiple providers, which is a big plus in my mind. You won't have to rewrite everything if you plan to migrate some instances to Rackspace later, or mix and match, etc. I haven't used it extensively but it looks fairly complete as far as EC2 goes. In `boto`'s favor it has support for nearly all of Amazon's web services, so if you plan to be Amazon-centric and use other services you'll probably want to use `boto`.

That said, try both packages and see which you prefer.

Comment: thank you; if I don't get any other answers, your answers will be picked as the winning one.

Comment: No problem. Why not try them both out and get back to us with your experiences as well?